# Given the probability of an event occuring on 1 day what is the probability of the event after n days

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

I have to draw a graph, but I cannot seem to make it happen.

I want a graph of the chance of finding a failure on a piece of equipment when checking after n-number of days.

I have historical data on the previous failures of the equipment, which follows a log-normal distribution. My data points are the average number of failures per equipment per day. I.e. the probability of x number of failures occurring in one day is given by a log-normal CDF, so that P[1 failure in a day] = F(1) (a pretty small number).

How can I then calculate the probability of finding 1 failure or maybe how many failures would I find if I only check on the second, third, and so on days?

Let me know if you need me to clarify anything. I cannot share my data, but if critical I might be able to create some dummy data.

Thank you in advance for your time!

Comment: Which probability distribution do we assume ? binomial, normal, poisson ?

Comment: The failures are assumed log-normally distributed.